# wxFileDialog always returns an empty string ""

Tags: wxwidgets

I am not 100% sure if this is the right place to ask but I have a problem with wxFileDialog. It always returns an empty string ""

```
    wxFileDialog* openFileDialog = new wxFileDialog(
this,
_("Open"),
wxEmptyString,
wxEmptyString,
"Vocab files (*.vocab)|*.vocab",
wxFD_,
OPEN|wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST);
    if (openFileDialog->ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
    {
        wxString path = openFileDialog->GetPath();
```

I haven't got the slightest clue as to why but I checked a few tutorials such as this one: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Writing_Your_First_Application-Common_Dialogs

and of course the manual but I only found that in the case that the user presses cancel (which I am not :)  ) GetPath(); returns a "".

I am using gcc, code blocks, wxWidgets 2.9.5 and run windows 7

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the code you show (not counting the unnecessary creation of the dialog on the heap, but this inefficient and inconvenient, not wrong). So either there is something wrong in your build of wxWidgets, or there is something catastrophic happening elsewhere in your program. To find out what it is, build and run the `dialogs` sample included in wxWidgets and use the file open dialog in it. If it works there, then at least your build of wxWidgets is sound.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) It turned out to be another one of those irrepeatable gcc / wxWidgets - *whoever the culprit might have been* mistakes. Restarted C::B and *puff* it worked - very strange.

I think I will change back to MSVC after this project - less hassle. Or maybe something went wrong when I build the wxWidgets.

You are right about the heap though.